# Change Chef server settings - port, url, https?

Tags: chef-infra

I was wondering if Chef server can run using http rather than https. And if it is possible to change the port. Maybe also the web root/url?

So for example in /etc/opschode/chef-server.rb. When I put

```
nginx['non_ssl_port'] = 8080
nginx['enable_non_ssl'] = true
nginx['x_forwarded_proto'] = 'http'
```

Chef will redirect http://myserver:8080 to https (port 443) and end up in a redirect loop of some sort.

Is it possible to change these types of settings in Chef?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for chef-server url in [omnibus-chef-server installation](https://github.com/chef/omnibus-chef-server), maybe that can help.

```
default['chef_server']['nginx']['url'] = "https://#{node['fqdn']}"
```

[Source](https://github.com/chef/omnibus-chef-server/blob/master/files/chef-server-cookbooks/chef-server/attributes/default.rb#L208)